# highstock format tooltip

Tags: jquery, highcharts

i have a problem con formatted tooltip in highstock charts.

the problem is what number show me :

```
120.9
1,234.03
3,567.98
```

How could change places the commas and points?

result:

```
120.9
1.234,03
3.567,98
```

and another question:
How could I put the above point value?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define it in lang options:

-decimalPoint http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.decimalPoint
-thousandsSep http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.thousandsSep